# Apply a subtitles file to a rented movie in iTunes

Tags: itunes, video, subtitle

I would like to watch movies rented from the UK iTunes store (on a Mac) with subtitles in another language. Unfortunately, movies on iTunes rarely have subtitles in any language besides English - but there are many fan-made subtitles files out there, and if this was a normal movie file it would be a simple matter to use them.

I'm guessing this is one of those questions where the answer is just "no", but is there any way to take a subtitles file downloaded from the internet, and use it while viewing a movie rented via iTunes?

Answer (score 2):

iTunes Videos are DRM-Protected and are not saved entirely on the local Drive AFAIK.

Therefore it is very hard to kind of "inject" a subtitle file.

I think Apple made this restriction due to quality reasons. They want a product to be very clean and complete as they can officially provide it.

Some Movies don't provide the Info officially and some other movies simply are'nt worth it..

So no,there is no official way. I guess you can only give Feedback to Apple, describing your problem and hoping to fix this in the future.

**BUT**
: There's always an [App](https://sites.google.com/a/tinwala.com/hussaintin/subtitle-player-1) for that !

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to that app! I'll try it next time this comes up. I wonder if it means we can't watch the movie full screen, though?

Comment: I'm would say you can watch it full-screen. But I didn't test it.